# iterate over rows in a large dataframe fast to determine contents for a column

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

For the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'chr_key':  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
                   'position': [123,124,125,126,127,128,129],
                   'hit_count': [20,19,18,17,16,15,14]})

df['strand'] = np.nan
```

I want to revise the `strand` column such that:

```
for i in range(0, len(df['position'])):
    if df['chr_key'][i] == df['chr_key'][i+1] and df['hit_count'][i] >= df['hit_count'][i+1]:
        df['strand'][i] = 'F'

    else:
        df['strand'][i] = 'R'
```

My actual `df` is >100k lines, so a for-loop is slow as one can imagine. Is there a fast way to achieve this?

I modified my original dataframe. Output will be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'chr_key' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], 'position' : [123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129], 'hit_count' : [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14], 'strand': ['R', 'R', 'F', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F']})
```

because there are only 3 `chr_key == 1` so when it comes to the third row, since it does not have an i+1 comparison row, the `strand` value will default to `F`

Comment: Can you provide the output you'd like given your input?

Comment: Edited my original dataframe and added an output!

Comment: Please fix your code example so it actually runs. I added the missing include. Is `df_rev` in line 4 supposed to be just `df`? Or is `df_dev` another existing dataframe?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it. It should all just be `df`. I think the answers shared below are quite helpful, I am testing them

Comment: You want to ***[tag:vectorize]*** your code. You can handle the second condition, that `hit_count` be decreasing, with `and (df['hit_count'].diff(-1) < 0)`

Comment: I would have titled this "Vectorize this condition in pandas"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'chr_key' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], 'position' : [123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129], 'hit_count' : [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14]})

df['strand'] = 'R'

idx_1 = df.chr_key == df.chr_key.shift(-1) 
idx_2 = df.hit_count >= df.hit_count.shift(-1)

df.loc[idx_1 & idx_2, 'strand'] = 'F'
```

Use `loc` or `iloc` methods to accessing pandas dataframe is a better practice: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

I am using `np.where` and `shift`

```
c1=(df.chr_key==df.chr_key.shift(-1))
c2=(df.hit_count>=df.hit_count.shift(-1))
df['strand']=np.where(c1&c2,'F','R')
```

Comment: I edited my question, originally it was 20, sorry Wen-Ben. I did find your shift to move 1 position extra in your original answer. Also `shift(-1)` vs `shift(1)`, is there a difference, coz in your original answer `shift` was a positive integer

Comment: @ManasiShah no need to worry , -1 shift up , 1 shift down